# Clearing ViewChildren subscriptions on destroy

Tags: angular

I have the following declaration in an Angular 8 component:

```
@ViewChildren(SelectComponent) selects: QueryList<SelectComponent>;
```

where `SelectComponent` is declared N times in an *ngFor.

To loop through the `selects` array when there are any edits, I subscribe to the changes:

```
this.selects.changes.subscribe(list => {
            list.forEach(item => {
                 alert('in forEach');
                // do something
            });
        });
```

The loop works fine, but the problem is that when I close and reopen the main component, the previous `selects` apparenty are not cleared, because the alert shows up several times.

How to clear/unsubscribe from these subscribes when the component is closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the same way you clear any other subscription, by unsubscribing in OnDestroy hook:

```
private sub: Subscription;

this.sub = this.selects.changes.subscribe(list => {
        list.forEach(item => {
             alert('in forEach');
            // do something
        });
    });

 ngOnDestroy() { this.sub.unsubscribe(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

From memory, you store the subscription in a variable inside your component

```js
this.mySubscription = this.selects.changes.subscribe(list => {
            list.forEach(item => {
                 alert('in forEach');
                // do something
            });
        });
```

and then you unsubscribe inside the `ngOnDestroy` part of the component lifecycle

```js
public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the NgOnDestroy method to your component - https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy  Adding that should clear any previous subscriptions on reloads.

Comment: `onDestroy` is just a hook, you still need to unsubscribe manually.